# How to check checkbox is checked or not while price slider event occurs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, checkbox, laravel-5

Here is my code,
For price slider:

```
$("#price-slider").ionRangeSlider({
    min: 130,
    max: 575,

    onChange : function (data) {
    var from_num = data.fromNumber;
    var to_num =data.toNumber;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'hotelresults',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
        from: from_num,
        to: to_num,
    },
        success: function(data){
            $('.hotel_list').html(data);
        }
    });
    }
});
```

When this action occurs I have to check whether the checkboxes are checked or not..

And if it's checked then I need to pass that checked checkbox value in this slider Ajax..

And at the same time its vice versa.

i.e: If the checkbox get checked it should pass the price slider value through its Ajax..

And here is my Checkbox click function

```
$( ".iCheck-helper" ).on( "click", function(){

    var sel = $('.i-check:checked').map(function(_, el) {
        return $(el).val();
    }).get();
// alert(sel);
    var nme = $('.i-check:checked').map(function() {
        return $(this).attr("name");
    }).get();
// alert(nme);
    if(!$(this).is(':checked')){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "hotelresults",
            data: {
                key : sel,
                name:nme,
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('.hotel_list').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Both these were pass the values through Ajax..

But I need to pass both values as I said already

Some one help me..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much `NiZa` I finally I found it... :)

```
var from_num = 130;
var to_num = 575;
var sel = "";
var nme = "";

function somethingChanged(from_num,to_num,sel,nme) {
    var sel = $('.i-check:checked').map(function(_, el) {
        return $(el).val();
    }).get();
    var nme = $('.i-check:checked').map(function() {
        return $(this).attr("name");
    }).get();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'hotelresults',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            from: from_num,
            to: to_num,
            key: sel,
            name: nme,
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('.hotel_list').html(data);
        }
    });
}

$("#price-slider").ionRangeSlider({
    min: 130,
    max: 575,

    onChange : function (data) {

        var from_num = data.fromNumber;
        var to_num =data.toNumber;
        somethingChanged(from_num,to_num,sel,nme);
    }
});

$( ".iCheck-helper" ).on( "click", function(){

    var price=$("#price-slider").val();

    var myarr = price.split(";");
    var from_num = myarr[0];
    var to_num = myarr[1];

    somethingChanged(from_num,to_num,sel,nme);
});
});
```

Here, In the `checkbox` click function I bought the values of priceslider from the priceslider textbox..

And after that I use `split` and pass those values to the `somethingChanged` function..

And also In the `priceslider` event I bought the checked checkbox values from the `somethingChanged`..

Here, the `$('.i-check:checked').map(function(_, el)` and `$('.i-check:checked').map(function()` call every time that both the event occur..

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't test it, but I think it should work. Let me know.

I created an extra function `somethingChanged()`. When you change your checkBox or RangeSlider, first the chosen values will be put. Then the function with the `ajax` call will firering.

```js
// Default values
var from_num = 130;
var to_num = 575;
var sel = "";
var nme = "";

function somethingChanged() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'hotelresults',
    type: 'POST',
    data: [
      {
        from: from_num,
        to: to_num
      }, {
        key: sel,
        name: nme
      }
    ],
    success: function(data) {
      $('.hotel_list').html(data);
    }
  });
}


$("#price-slider").ionRangeSlider({
  min: 130,
  max: 575,

  onChange: function(data) {
    from_num = data.fromNumber;
    to_num = data.toNumber;
    somethingChanged();
  }
});

$(".iCheck-helper").on("click", function() {

  sel = $('.i-check:checked').map(function(_, el) {
    return $(el).val();
  }).get();

  nme = $('.i-check:checked').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr("name");
  }).get();

  if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
    somethingChanged();
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes I am, it will pass both values, depends if you changed something yes or not. Otherwise it will pass the default values.

Comment: Here you set all the four values `from_num` `to_num` `sel` `nme` as default.. If the event occurs it took which values??the changable values or default values!!...

Comment: Ajax called perfectly..But it return only default value for both Checkbox and slider Ajax...

Comment: Are you sure? What are the results if you do a `console.log()` of all values inside the `somethingChanged()` function and before the `ajax` call. And you are sure that you changed the checkBox and slider?

Comment: I tried like this way `function somethingChanged(from_num,to_num,sel,nme) ` both the change and click function..So it pass the `nme` and `sel` values only in the checkbox event..And in the slider event it only pass the default values for all

Comment: Sorry!..it pass the `from_num` and `to_num` values in slider event and `sel` and `nme` values in checkbox event correctly..But it took the remaning from default values

Comment: So it's working? You should change the 'data' property aswell into this `data:  [{ from: from_num,   to: to_num } , { key: sel, name: nme }],`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105670/discussion-between-suganya-and-niza).